# SEO on GitLab/GitHub Pages

Tags: web-hosting, search-engine-indexing, github, static-content, single-page-application

GitLab/GitHub pages are excellent ways to host static (or SPA) application especially because the code and deployment resides in the same place.

However, does the use of GitLab/GitHub pages instead of dedicated web hosting system has any impact on SEO and the ranking of the hosted site (with custom domain)?

Comment: Github pages is a web hosting system.   I'm not sure what you mean by "dedicated."   Do you mean a company that specializes in web hosting?

Comment: Yes exactly. By "dedicated", I mean the companies that offer web-hosting solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question, because we are indeed seeing more Github results seeping into SERP's.

While Github and Gitlab aren't exactly SEO-focused (no amazing SEO tool suite), as they were not originally meant for websites that rank highly, if you write titles and copy that are well-phrased and answer the searchers' intent, you will rank.

For instance, try Googling "supplychain object standard" - an AdTech standard for bid requests and transparency in the supply chain thereof. While a relatively niche concept, it is a big deal in the AdTech world. Here is the SERP result:

[image: Supplychain Object Standard]

The Github page ranks third. The first two are from IAB, which is a heavy hitter organization in that corner of the industry and can be very hard to outrank.

A quick search does bring up [SEO functionality](https://github.blog/2016-05-10-better-discoverability-for-github-pages-sites/) for [Github Pages](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/05/10/github-pages-seo/) and [Jekyll](https://www.readmodwrite.com/2019-01-18-jekyll-seo-tags/), but it looks to be pretty basic and manual. Which, with great content, might be all you need.

In short, I would not choose this option if you want to SEO-engineer the heck out of your site, but if that's not the primary concern, by all means.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. If I understood correctly, SEO effectiveness is the combination of website (content + optimisations included in the front-end) and hosting provider. Unless the need of the site is not "The best SEO optimised website", using GitLab Pages should be fine.

Comment: Hi @Anand, the hosting provider has some bearing on SEO, particularly when it comes to site speed or SEO plugins they can offer. In this case, the provider is focused on project-based websites as opposed to, say, e-commerce. That's why Jekyll is the preferred blogging solution as opposed to say, WordPress or Drupal. But yes, if intricate SEO is not the main concern, and you don't mind more hands-on management of these aspects, it should suffice.